# pip install darknetpy not working, "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1"

Tags: python, darknet

I am trying to install darknetpy using these instructions:

https://pypi.org/project/darknetpy/

however every time I run 'pip install darknetpy' I get:

```
$ pip install darknetpy
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting darknetpy
  Using cached darknetpy-4.1.tar.gz (9.4 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\paddy\appdata\local\temp\tmp9kl8jm'
       cwd: c:\users\paddy\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-eqp5it\darknetpy
  Complete output (2 lines):
  c:\python27\python.exe: No module named pip
  Please install setuptools-rust package
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python27\python.exe' 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\paddy\appdata\local\temp\tmp9kl8jm' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have installed setuptools-rust but still get the same errors as above.

I am on a Windows 10 laptop and using Git Bash as my emulator. Please help!

Comment: It seems you are using python 2.7. Install python 3.8.5(latest version as of today) from python website (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/python-3.8.5.exe) and try again

Comment: Did you see the `Please install setuptools-rust package` in the error message?

Comment: Using a later version of python throws the same error (I've used both 3.7.7 and 2.7.17 i think). I do get the "Please install setuptools-rust package" when I try installing it in Spyder. But I'm pretty sure i've installed setuptools-rust...

Comment: had try python 3.8.5 and it did not work. And it is not work even in Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to install darknetpy successfully:

pip install https://github.com/danielgatis/darknetpy/raw/master/dist/darknetpy-4.2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl